# how to get the date of last week's (tuesday or any other day) in php?

Tags: php, date

I think its possible but i cant come up with the right algorithm for it.

What i wanted to do was:

If today is monday feb 2 2009, how would i know the date of last week's tuesday? Using that same code 2 days after, i would find the same date of last week's tuesday with the current date being wednesday, feb 4 2009.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know there is an accepted answer already, but imho it does not meet the second requirement that was asked for. In the above case, strtotime would yield yesterday if used on a wednesday. So, just to be exact you would still need to check for this:

```
$tuesday = strtotime('last Tuesday');
// check if we need to go back in time one more week
$tuesday = date('W', $tuesday)==date('W') ? $tuesday-7*86400 : $tuesday;
```

---

As davil pointed out in his comment, this was kind of a quick-shot of mine. The above calculation will be off by one once a year due to daylight saving time. The good-enough solution would be:

```
$tuesday = date('W', $tuesday)==date('W') ? $tuesday-7*86400+7200 : $tuesday;
```

If you need the time to be 0:00h, you'll need some extra effort of course.

Comment: This won't work 1 week per year when Sunday only has 23 hours due to DST switching (the resulting timestamp will be for Monday 23:00). Replace "7*86400" with "7*86400 + 7200". Of course in that case the time will not always be 0:00, but the date will be DST safe!

Comment: You're right, this was kind of a quick-shot. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: thanks for that, i didn't notice it until today (its wednesday now)
T_T i owe you more now hehe

Comment: @cg The OP asked for Tuesday of last week, not last Tuesday, which could be of this week (if today is Wednesday, 'last Tuesday' would be yesterday, not the Tuesday of last week), thus it's incorrect. The correct and accurate answer as I mentioned below is strtotime('tuesday last week')

Comment: Ok, so my answer is correct after all, if maybe not as concise. It does yield last week's Tuesday in those cases. Have you even read it?

Answer (score 24):

Most of these answers are either too much, or technically incorrect because "last Tuesday" doesn't necessarily mean the Tuesday from last week, it just means the previous Tuesday, which could be within the same week of "now".

The correct answer is:

```
strtotime('tuesday last week')
```

Comment: @STTLCU yeah I don't know why the highest voted one is considered correct when if you run it on a Wednesday it'll basically return yesterday's Tuesday, not last week's, which is not what OP is asking for

Comment: I agree with @STT LCU. This should be the accepted answer as I came across the same problem that was using 'last monday' which picked up yesterday

Comment: Works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 14):

PHP actually makes this really easy:

```
echo strtotime('last Tuesday');
```

See the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) documentation.

Comment: T.T why haven't i seen that in the documentation T.T
thanks a lot i owe you

Comment: this actually does not give you "tuesday of last week" but the last tuesday (which can be the same week... if it is friday)

Comment: Exactly @garyee - check my answer below

Comment: List of available words is here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: `last tuesday` returns tuesday date from the same week, not from last week. `tuesday last week` does return tuesday date from last week.

Answer (score 3):

Working solution:

```
$z = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last Saturday"));
$z = (date('W', strtotime($z)) == date('W')) ? (strtotime($z)-7*86400+7200) : strtotime($z);
print date("Y-m-d", $z);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use manual calculation, use DateTime object instead. It has proper implementation, takes into account leap years, yeap seconds, etc.

```
$today = new \DateTime();
$today->modify('tuesday last week');
```

The modify method modifies the date relative to it's state, so if you set the date to a different date, it calculates it relative to it.

```
$date = new \DateTime('2020-01-01');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2020-01-01

$date->modify('tuesday last week');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2019-12-24
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot strtotime for second argument of date('W', $tuesday)
hmm.

convert $tuesday to timestamp before "$tuesday-7*86400+7200"

mde.

Answer (score 0):

```
// test: find last date for each day of the week
foreach (array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun') as $day) {
    print $day . " => " . date('m/d/Y', last_dayofweek($day)) . "\n";
}

function last_dayofweek($day)
{
    // return timestamp of last Monday...Friday
    // will return today if today is the requested weekday
    $day = strtolower(substr($day, 0, 3));
    if (strtolower(date('D')) == $day)
        return strtotime("today");
    else
        return strtotime("last {$day}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $currentDay = date('D');
    echo "Today-".$today = date("Y-m-d");
    echo "Yesterday-".$yesterday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('yesterday'));
    echo "Same day last week-".$same_day_last_week = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('last '.$currentDay));
?>
```