# Display last (past) Friday date on website

Tags: php, wordpress

This is what I currently use to display the date for this coming Friday.

```php
$date_friday = date('F j', strtotime('Friday'));
print $date_friday;
```

What should I use to display the date for the past (last) Friday?

Comment: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: I am using Wordpress and a PHP addon.  This works perfectly and has for a long time.  The current complete line of code is [insert_php]$date_friday = date('F j', strtotime('Friday')); print $date_friday;[/insert_php]

Comment: Related maybe even a possible duplicate due to this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/32419822/1078886], [http://stackoverflow.com/a/17116180/1078886]

Comment: The solution provided on the page did work. :-)  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to a similar question (actually the same but for tuesday) :
[how to get the date of last week's (tuesday or any other day) in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502535/how-to-get-the-date-of-last-weeks-tuesday-or-any-other-day-in-php)

`strtotime('last friday')` should work.

Comment: I tried that but it does not display any value.  I am using Wordpress and a PHP plugin.  The below text displays the coming Friday date but I cannot get either of the two provided solutions to display any date. [insert_php]$date_friday = date('F j', strtotime('Friday')); print $date_friday;[/insert_php]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```
$date_friday = date('F j', strtotime('Friday - 7 days'));
```

This code will use current friday for get friday which was before.

Comment: Does not work when using in Wordprss although my current code does work and displays the upcoming Friday perfectly. [insert_php]$date_friday = date('F j', strtotime('Friday - 7 days'));[/insert_php]

Answer (score 0):

Got it to display October 9 using the code below in Wordpress.

```php
$date_friday = date('F j', strtotime('last Friday'));
print $date_friday;
```